Question about postdoctoral salary in China
I have been offered a postdoc position in Shenzhen. The salary salary condition is 240,000/260,000 chinese yuan/year, but will be dispersed as 5000/6800 per month and "pass open project exam" 180,000 one time, the 180,000 normally will be given around 6-9 months after people join the group.
I don't understand what "pass open project" means. Also, is it possible to survive on 5000 per month salary in Shenzhen? Is the accommodation provided by University?

Have you asked anyone at the university yet? Maybe your future advisor?

I think there are probably better StackExchange sites for the question about livability-- Personal Finance, maybe? Or Travel? The "pass open project exam" question, however, seems at home here.

I don't think this is out of scope, although the expats stackexchange (if it survived?) might be better for part of the question. VOting to leave open.

It is the best, of course, to ask someone at the university who speaks both English and Chinese well, or a trusted colleague who knows Chinese. You could also check with an expat working at the university. If needed, you might want to talk to a Chinese lawyer focusing on foreign workers.
In the context of Shenzhen, it's likely (though you should confirm this in writing) that the 180k refers to the annual postdoctoral living allowance provided by the Shenzhen government. This allowance isn’t technically a salary (it is not paid by the employer); it’s a tax-free stipend for up to two years.
The "open project exam" is probably a poor translation of "开题考核," which literally means "assessment for opening a project." This is the approval process for starting your research project and is mostly a formality. The same term is also used for exams that approve thesis projects for doctoral or master's students (but there sometimes it is more than a formality).
You need to pass this internal assessment (i.e. get the official approval for your postdoc proposal) before you can apply for the living allowance from the government. There's also an annual or mid-term review that you need to pass to get the allowance for the second year.
Shenzhen Postdoctoral Funding Management Measures (it will be replaced soon but the principles are the same)：

Article 7
流动站在站博士后生活补贴标准在省财政给予每人每年资助15万元基础上，给予每人每年6万元配套资助；工作站、创新基地及其他单位，在站博士后生活补贴标准为每人每年18万元。
The living allowance standard for postdoctoral researchers in mobile stations is set at 150,000 RMB per person per year, provided by provincial finances, with an additional 60,000 RMB per person per year in matching funds. For those in workstations, innovation bases, and other units, the living allowance is set at 180,000 RMB per person per year.
在站博士后生活补贴的资助期限不超过2年。
The funding period for the in-station postdoctoral living allowance shall not exceed two years.
Article 8
在站博士后人员应当在开题考核及中期考核合格后6个月内，向市人力资源保障部门申请在站生活补贴。
Postdoctoral researchers must apply to the Municipal Human Resources and Social Security Department for the in-station living allowance within six months of passing the project proposal assessment and mid-term assessment.


As Allure pointed out in their answer, you need to ask someone from the department there what this means exactly. There is a massive difference between 6800 RNB/ month and 260.000 RNB per year and you need to understand which of the two you are getting under which conditions (and whether these conditions are mostly under your control or under someone else's).
For the standard of living, this sort of depends on what you compare it to. First the average local Chinese person in Shenzen lives on less than 5000 RNB per month, so this is definitely possible.
If you get a salary of 260.000 RNB per year this will get you a standard of living that is roughly comparable to a postdoc standard of living in Western Europe. Housing cost will be expensive, think Paris or London for a comparable quality and price. Everything else will be much cheaper, most commodities (food, clothing, etc) roughly half the price of Western Europe for a similar quality, everything mostly service (taxis, hair cuts, etc even cheaper).
This also menas that if the university provides accomodation for you that is very valuable. Definetely ask them about it, even if you have to pay for it there is a high probability this will be a much better deal that what you could get yourself on the regular housing market.
If you have a postdoc offer from Shenzen University I would expect a salary package that comes to roughly a Western standard, so I would assume you get the full 260.000 RNB, but make sure you understand the details before you sign it.

Sounds like the work of someone who's not fluent in English (very common in China).
Best to ask your contact there to clarify.
